# Mocking the response of XmlResponse::getResultCode not working

Tags: 8, commerce, testing

Following is the code that I'm using to mock the response of `XmlResponse::getResultCode` as `Ok`, but it isn't working, I'm not sure what exactly is going wrong here:

```php
$response = $this->createPartialMock('\CommerceGuys\AuthNet\Response\XmlResponse', ['getResultCode']);
$response->expects($this->any())->method('getResultCode')->will($this->returnValue('Ok'));

$client = $this->createMock('\GuzzleHttp\Client');
$client->expects($this->any())->method('request')->withAnyParameters()->will($this->returnValue($response));
$this->container->set('http_client', $client);

$clientFactory = $this->createMock('\Drupal\Core\Http\ClientFactory');
$clientFactory->expects($this->any())->method('fromOptions')->will($this->returnValue($client));
$this->container->set('http_client_factory', $clientFactory);
```

I've even tried the `prophesize` way, but that's not working either:

```php
$response = $this->prophesize('\CommerceGuys\AuthNet\Response\XmlResponse');
$response->getResultCode()->willReturn('Ok');
```

My goal is to mock the response of [`XmlResponse::getResultCode`](https://github.com/commerceguys/authnet/blob/master/src/Response/XmlResponse.php) to return string `Ok`.

Trying the above approach for the D8 site with PHPUnit 7.5.20 using Kernal Testcase.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I resolved this a while ago:

Create a new fixture, let's say `tests/fixtures/payment-response.xml` that'll contain the following response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<createTransactionResponse xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
    <refId>123456</refId>
    <messages>
        <resultCode>Ok</resultCode>
        <message>
            <code>I00001</code>
            <text>Successful.</text>
        </message>
    </messages>
    <transactionResponse>
        <responseCode>1</responseCode>
        <authCode>UGELQC</authCode>
        <avsResultCode>E</avsResultCode>
        <cavvResultCode/>
        <transId>2148061808</transId>
        <refTransID/>
        <transHash>0B428D8A928AAC61121AF2F6EAC5FF3F</transHash>
        <accountNumber>XXXX0015</accountNumber>
        <accountType>Mastercard</accountType>
        <message>
            <code>1</code>
            <description>This transaction has been approved.</description>
        </message>
        <userFields>
            <userField>
                <name>MerchantDefinedFieldName1</name>
                <value>MerchantDefinedFieldValue1</value>
            </userField>
            <userField>
                <name>favorite_color</name>
                <value>lavender</value>
            </userField>
        </userFields>
        <networkTransId>123456789NNNH</networkTransId>
    </transactionResponse>
</createTransactionResponse>
```

Rest, all I need to do is update my PHP logic to fetch the response as data provided by `payment-response.xml`

```php
    $response = new Response(200, [], file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../fixtures/payment-response.xml'));
    $client = $this->createPartialMock(Client::class, ['request']);
    $client->expects(self::once())->method('request')->withAnyParameters()->willReturn($response);
    $this->container->set('http_client', $client);

    $clientFactory = $this->createPartialMock(ClientFactory::class, ['fromOptions']);
    $clientFactory->expects(self::any())->method('fromOptions')->willReturn($client);
    $this->container->set('http_client_factory', $clientFactory);
```

Comment: This can also be done with middleware for tests to intercept HTTP calls.

Comment: Thanks, @Kevin, could you please elaborate more on this? I'm interested in knowing the middleware part.